# Rearranging infinite summation sign

Tags: real-analysis, summation, proof-explanation

My textbook contains this step and I can't follow:

First, it gives the definition of cosine as a series:

$$ cos(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}  $$

Secondly, it proves an identity, where the step happens:

$$ cos(x) * cos(y)=
\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!} (-1)^{n-k} \frac{y^{2(n-k)}}{(2(n-k))!}$$

If you plug in the definition above into $cos(x) * cos(y)$ it should give you 
$$ cos(x)*cos(y)= (\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}) (\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k \frac{y^{2k}}{(2k)!})$$

**Therefore, I assume, there has to have been a step, where this happend:**

$$ cos(x)*cos(y)= (\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}) (\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k \frac{y^{2k}}{(2k)!})=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!} (-1)^{n-k} \frac{y^{2(n-k)}}{(2(n-k))!}$$

How are these two terms equal? I tried computing a few specific examples of this kind or rearrangement and it didn't work out. Would we not sum additional things each time, because for every iteration of the first sum signs we sum all the terms up to n again in the second iteration?

I added the original equation from the book, but it seems to be exactly the one I typed above. I guess the book is just wrong then

[image: excerpt from the book]

Comment: Try referring to [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gyLkY.png).

Comment: Also, the first sum is wrong.  Consider $x=0$ and $y=10$.  The second sum is also probably wrong according to this case.

Comment: Isn't the first sum just the series definition of cosine? http://math2.org/math/algebra/functions/sincos/expansions.htm

Comment: It is the definition of one cosine.  Not two multiplied together, it doesn't work like that.

Comment: I tried to correct it, how about now?

Comment: I honestly don't see how the last sum can be equal to the others.  They don't even agree for $x=0$ and $y=10$ as I've already mentioned.

Comment: Thank you then. I posted the original excerpt just in case, but I'm pretty sure I did not make a typo

Comment: The last sum is exactly like he wrote it. And the sum before that is just the definition of cosine

Comment: Whoa, wait a minute, I'm not sure if the first pair of sums is correct.

Comment: That's not a normal definition of cosine by any means

Comment: Well, in this case, you wrote the first line wrong.  The second sum should have an upper bound.  Secondly, refer to my first comment.

Comment: This is the most laborious way of proving this identity. Infinite products are far easier than series for this, or the DE relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an application of the *[Cauchy product of power  series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Cauchy_product_of_two_power_series)*.

> We    obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \cos (x)\cos(y)&=\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}\right)
> \left(\sum_{l=0}^\infty (-1)^l\frac{y^{2l}}{(2l)!}\right)\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{{k+l=n}\atop{k,l\geq 0}}
> (-1)^k\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}(-1)^l\frac{y^{2l}}{(2l)!}\right)\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^n
> (-1)^k\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}(-1)^{n-k}\frac{y^{2(n-k)}}{(2n-2k)!}\right)\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{1}{(2n)!}\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n}{2k}
> x^{2k}y^{2(n-k)}\right)\tag{3}\\
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we rearrange the terms according to increasing $n$ and the corresponding contributions  from $x$ terms and $y$ terms.
- In (2) we *substitute* the index $l$ by $n-k$.
- In (3) we collect $(-1)^k$ and $(-1)^{n-k}$ and use the binomial coefficient
  \begin{align*}
  \binom{2n}{2k}=\frac{(2n)!}{(2k)!(2n-2k)!}
  \end{align*}

Comment: Thank your for being so thorough, the comments were exactly what I needed!

Comment: @plsmakemedomath: You're welcome!  Good to see the answer is useful! :-)